# Portable Electron app does not allow file drop

Tags: angular, electron

My app is Angular based (17.2.2). Electron used is 29.0.1. I have `portable` and `nsis` targets (Windows). My app allows external file drops. This works well when using the `nsis` based installer, however the portable build disallows file drops. Needless to say both builds are produced off of the same Angular build so it has to be something Electron specific. The app is not running elevated. Windows Explorer also is not elevated.

Is this something inherent to portable apps? Am I missing some configuration tweak to make this possible?

Comment: do you mean the app is open and you drop a file into the open window?
The portable is created by electron-builder, i guess? that portable is actually a self extracting archive which extracts to the temp folder on windows and then starts the .exe there. So it could be an issue with that.

Comment: So portable and nsis are created in the same build process. The nsis installed app works just fine but dropping a file anywhere on the portable app's main window is denied. The `dragenter` and friends are never fired.

Comment: try to run portable exe as admin, if that works. i bet it has something to do with the temp folder and files being extracted there. It is not an electron issue, but a electron-builder issue then. electron-builder is no official electron tool.

Comment: Roger that. Thanks. I am obviously not an expert but nothing more than an Electron consumer. Running the portable app as admin would not work because drag and drop is prevent by default from non admin run Windows Explorer to an elevated process.